# Transform a std::vector of boost.asio::ip::address via boost::algorithm::join and boost::adaptors::transformed

Tags: c++, boost, functional-programming

short question. I do not know how to properly use `boost::adaptors::transformed` with `boost::algorithm::join`. The following does not work:

```
boost::algorithm::join(addresses |
                       boost::adaptors::transformed(std::mem_f(&boost::asio::ip::address_v4::to_string)), ", ");
```

I do not understand the syntax of `boost::adaptors::transformed`. How do I call the memeber function for each object in the `std::vector`?

Currently im concatenating the string manually, but I would prefer the functional approach outlined above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`to_string` has overloads, so you need to specify which one you want (use a static_cast)

```
boost::algorithm::join(
        addresses | 
        transformed(std::mem_fn(static_cast<std::string (address_v4::*)() const>(&boost::asio::ip::address_v4::to_string))), ", ");
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bec6288fc3c0a1da)**

Note also that `to_string()` in this overload may throw.

---

With c++11, much prefer the lambda syntax:

```
boost::algorithm::join(
        addresses | 
        transformed([](address_v4 const& a) { return a.to_string(); }), ", ");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Info: I have been only able to use the C++11 version with the `BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE` preprocessor macro enabled. I am using GCC 4.7.1 and Boost 1.49.0.

Answer (score 0):

@sehe's answer is absolutely correct. I've just wanted to add that one may want use the base class `boost::asio::ip::address` instead of the specialization `boost::asio::ip::address_v4` by doing the following:

```
boost::algorithm::join(
    addresses |
        boost::adaptors::transformed(
            [](boost::asio::ip::address const &kIpAddress) {
              return kIpAddress.to_string();
            }),
    ", "))
```